# How to Listen For Failed Login Attempt - Kotlin MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication

So I have followed the advice of 'yoursTruly' and created an AuthStateListener in my Activity (as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CXUNcsQPgQ&feature=youtu.be).

This works really well, in the fact that the Activity is simply listening to Authentication and will divert to next Activity if someone logs in and the Fragment simply calls signIn(email, password) via the ViewModel.

However, can not see a way to look for failed login attempts (so the UI will just look like it is unresponsive).

My structure is as follows: **Activity** -> **Fragment** -> **ViewModel** -> **Repository**.

I'm using DataBinding & Navigation.

**Activity**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(this)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this)
    }

    override fun onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

        // Will only fire if state has changed!

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Welcome to the Locators App!\n\nPlease login to continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }

        firebaseAuth.currentUser?.getIdToken(true)
            ?.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                val idToken = result.token
                Toast.makeText(this,"User Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d(TAG, "GetTokenResult result (check this at https://jwt.io/ = $idToken")
                goToSiteActivity()
            }
    }

    private fun goToSiteActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, SiteActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding: LoginFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.login_fragment, container, false)

        binding.apply {
            loginPasswordResetText.setOnClickListener{
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_loginPasswordResetFragment)
            }
            loginButton.setOnClickListener{
                loginProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                val email = loginEmailEditText.text.toString()
                val password = loginPasswordEditText.text.toString()
                if(validateForm(email, password)) {
                    loginViewModel.loginUser(email, password)

                }
                loginProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE

            }
            loginNewUserText.setOnClickListener{
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_loginUserRegisterFragment)
            }
        }
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    }


    private fun validateForm(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

        var validForm = true

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            loginEmailEditText.error = "Please enter valid email address!"
            validForm = false
        } else loginEmailEditText.error = null

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            loginPasswordEditText.error = "Please enter password!"
            validForm = false
        } else loginPasswordEditText.error = null

        Log.d(TAG,"validateForm: (email = $email, password =  $password, validateForm = $validForm)")

        return validForm
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun loginUser (email: String, password: String) {
        firestoreRepository.loginUser(email, password)
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class FirestoreRepository {

        var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        var failedLogin: Boolean = false

        fun loginUser(email: String, password: String) {
                failedLogin = false

                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")

                        } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", it.exception)
                                failedLogin = true
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

This question ties in with a larger query of, if you create LiveData in Repo, how do you Observe from ViewModel (i.e. what do you use as the LifeCycleOwner?), but I will ask on a seperate question..

Comment: This question looks like android-specific. Please add 'android' tag if did understand correctly.

Comment: Android added..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AuthStateListener is not sufficient to determine when a sign-in fails.  It will only tell you when the state of the user changes between signed in and signed out.

You will have to use the result of `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` to determine if the sign-in failed.  It looks like you already have some code there to handle that case, but you're not doing much with the error other than setting a property.

What you should do instead is have your `loginUser` ViewModel method return a LiveData that gets notified when the sign-in succeeds or fails.  You will have to wire up the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to change the state of that LiveData, and your view will have to observe that LiveData to show a message to the user if necessary.

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for the response (again) - I have tried that, but I am struggling with the code in the ViewModel.  Specifically, the LifecycleOwner of the Observer..

Should I just use observeForever and remove observer manually when the VM is destroyed?

Comment: If that works for you.  If you have a new problem, I suggest posting a new question to explain what the issue is and what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: My post was moderated (hopefully this comment is ok!), but for completeness, I have updated my question here with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874102/how-to-return-livedata-from-repository